# How use regex for long text?

Tags: php, regex

I use this regex, but not work!

```
href="/name/nm(\d{7})\?ref.*>(.*)</a>.*class="(.*)">(.*)</span>
```

Link : https://regex101.com/r/JWyIJ2/1

Output:

> Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your
>   expression has been halted. To find out more what this is, please read
>   the following article: Runaway Regular Expressions
>
> I recommend you launch the debugger in the menu to the left and
>   analyze the data to find out the cause.

Comment: Show your input and expected output (Edit your question) and explain what desn't Work.

Comment: "not work", tells us nothing. no idea what you are trying to  match

Comment: @PoulBak my input is very long. i paste errors and my input is here : https://regex101.com/r/JWyIJ2/1

Comment: @IdontDownVote i added error to question and added input in https://regex101.com/r/JWyIJ2/1

Comment: Don't ever parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: your link shows nothing.

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. You can probably use a parser but without a description is hard to help you.

Comment: @IdontDownVote this link open for me : https://regex101.com/r/JWyIJ2/1

Comment: Well, have you looked at the debugger output? `.*` is usually inadvisable.

Comment: ok link works in chrome but not firefox, anyway dont do this, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score -1):

In my daily job I use this one against very long (more than 1GB) text files:
^[^|]*$

Comment: Exactly why is this an answer to the question`.